# how azure devop yaml determine which branch of source code it should checkout?

Tags: azure-devops

My azure build pipeline is in classic UI mode and I am trying to learn YAML and convert. One thing I learned is that one YAML can be used to build by multiple branches. For example:

```
trigger:
- master
- R_Current_Sprint
```

My understanding is if there is PR to update R_Current_Sprint branch or Master branch, then this build will be triggered (it can work out if the R_Current_Sprint branch or master branch should be checked out base on that).

But if I just click an enqueue button, how devop works out which branch should the sources from? Do I somehow need to set a default branch?

Comment: Hi daxu, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default branch for manual builds in pipeline settings.
Open `Edit` mode for pipeline and in the top corner choose `Triggers` from more option list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
how azure devop yaml determine which branch of source code it should checkout?
```

In Azure DevOps you don't have [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#checkout) to directly get only part of the repository,

What you are referring actually is multiple branches trigger. For manually build, "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" is what you are looking for.

Since you are using YAML, go to your pipeline, click the **eclipse** the 3 dots in the upper right corner, choose **triggers**, go to **YAML** page as shown in below pic

[image]

[image]

Below is the description for **The build pipeline's default branch** build filter in  pipeline. Hope it is helpful for your understanding. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#continuous-deployment-triggers) for more information.

> Alternatively, you can specify a filter to use the default branch specified in the build pipeline. This is useful when, for example, the default build branch changes in every development sprint. It means you don't need to update the trigger filter across all release pipelines for every change - instead you just change the default branch in the build pipeline.